# Redirecionar Route direto para a view

Tags: laravel, route

Já li em alguns lugares que o correto é apontar a rota para um *controller* e então redirecionar para uma *view*. Eu faco isso mesmo quando não irei passar nenhuma variável para essa *view*?

Nesse caso, vou ter uma página "sobre nós", onde terá apenas um texto estático descrevendo a empresa, é errado que a *route* redirecione direto para a *view* que contém o texto?

Comment: Se está usando no arquivo de rotas colocar `Route::get('sobre-nos', function(){ return view(""); });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não errado, mas também não é aconcelhavel. Você pode passar ao criar a rota:

```
Route::post('/sobre-nos', function(){
     return view('sobrenos');
}
```

O "correto" seria chamar o controller:

```
Route::post('/sobre-nos', 'SiteController@sobrenos');
```

E no controller criar o metodo sobrenos:

```
public function sobrenos(){
     return view('sobrenos')
}
```